# «В контейнере» — какой член предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, существительные, члены-предложения, обстоятельство

> *Да, наверное, я возьму обед **в контейнере***.

Можно ли к слову ***в контейнере*** задать вопрос ***где?*** (Возьму — где? — в контейнере.)
Если так, то *в контейнере* — обстоятельство?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое
В контейнере (*в чём?*) или в контейнере (*где?*) — нет разницы, какой именно задан вопрос к слову. Это в любом случае **существительное** в предложном падеже (с предлогом).
Вопрос необходимо было сформулировать так: *какой член предложения?*

Второе
Разберемся, собственно, с тем, что такое [контейнер](http://endic.ru/enc_sovet/Kontener-27572.html).
Это может быть и большая стандартная ёмкость для перевозки или хранения, или специальная (обычно небольшая) тара для сбережения продуктов питания (например, бутербродов или другой готовой еды).

Третье
Так как нет контекста, включаем воображение.

*Да, наверное, я возьму обед* (в чём?) *в контейнере.* Это дополнение.
Обед ваш находится не в бумаге, не в пакете, а именно (в чём?) — в контейнере.

*Да, наверное, я возьму обед* (где?) *в контейнере.* Это обстоятельство.
Обед ваш находится не в холодильнике, не на полке, не в шкафчике, а именно (где?) — в контейнере, в котором их [обедов] предостаточно. Кстати, в этой обстановке можно использовать и вопрос "откуда?". (— Откуда ты его возьмешь? —  Я возьму обед из контейнера.)
Такая ситуация похожа на конструкцию хранения пищи в самолетах: небольшие персональные контейнеры (коробочки) с едой содержатся в объемных контейнерах, их вмещающих.

И последнее
В конце предложения ставится точка.

P. S. Шапка вопроса до правки: "Часть речи. Какая?".

Comment: Римма, я тоже думал над этим вопросом. А может ли быть вариант (ведь контекста нет), когда задаем такой вопрос: *обед (какой?) в контейнере*? Тогда это будет несогласованное определение.

Comment: Ну да... Теоретически это возможно. Мое бесконтекстное воображение ограничилось только самыми вероятными примерами. И я, собственно, отвечала на вопрос "Можно ли к словам *в контейнере* задать вопрос *где*?"